# list child page items (1 level with meta keys)

Tags: wordpress

I need to have a index page and it can pull out the title (with link), meta key description and meta key image (meta keys from custom fields) of its child pages, but only one level down.

e.g. I have a index page call WORK, and few child index PRINT, WEB. there will be some pages under PRINT and WEB as well, but I don't want them to be shown on the WORK index. I only need to have PRINT and WEB to be listed and with the meta keys.

Anybody can help please? many thanks!

Comment: Say wha? Could you try explaining it a little clearer, perhaps with an example? :)

Answer (score 0):

Try putting:

```
query_posts("cat=1,-2,-3");
```

...Before the loop. Replace the numbers after cat= with the category IDs in question; using the negative symbol (such as "-2,-3") excludes a category.

To do this more programmatically:

```
$parent = 1; //catID of parent
$children = get_categories("child_of=".$parent);
foreach ($children as $child) {$excluded .= "-".$child->term_id.","; //add minus sign}
$excluded = rtrim($excluded, ","); //remove last comma

query_posts("cat=".$parent.",".$excluded);
```